# PHPMailer + reCAPTCHA or any other anti-spam - problem

Tags: phpmailer, recaptcha, spam-prevention

I've made a contact form on my friends website and everything works correctly but he gets a lot of spam offers like bitcoins/porn etc. I tried to setup reCAPTCHA but that didn't work.

I'm using PHPMailer (previous I used google API for mail but that kind of form gets a lot more spam offers) and I can't find a way to protect against bots.

I'm wondering - maybe that the mailer script is running in background after pushing the submit button is the problem? Maybe that's why it skipping the reCAPTCHA.

I tried everything - changing the max length of inputs, their names... my last try was this recaptcha:

https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

**My code:**

**TOP of the index.php:**

```
    <?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$secret  = '*****';
$sitekey = '*****';
$captcha = new \Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\NoCaptcha($secret, $sitekey);

if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($captcha->verifyResponse($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        //proceed further
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect captcha";
    }
}
?>
```

**My form:**

```
 <form name="test" role="form" action="sendmail.php" method="POST" onSubmit="alert('Dziękujemy za kontakt :)'); window.location.reload();"  >


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>Imię i nazwisko:</label>
            </div>                    
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input maxlength="30" name="a1" required="required" type="text"  placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" required/>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input maxlength="30" name="a2" required="required" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>Telefon:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input maxlength="30" name="a3" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Numer telefonu"  required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>Temat:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input maxlength="30" name="a4" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Temat wiadomości" required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>Wiadomość:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <textarea name="a5" placeholder="Wiadomość"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <?php echo $captcha->display(); ?>
            <input name="myFormSubmitted" type="submit" value="Wyślij" style="margin-top:10px;">
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
    <?php echo $captcha->renderJs(); ?>
```

**Sendmail.php** :

```
    <?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 * This uses traditional id & password authentication - look at the gmail_xoauth.phps
 * example to see how to use XOAUTH2.
 * The IMAP section shows how to save this message to the 'Sent Mail' folder using IMAP commands.
 */

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
// SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
// SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
//Set the encryption mechanism to use - STARTTLS or SMTPS
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = '*****';

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = '*****';

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo( $_POST['mail']);

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('****');

$mail->IsHTML(true); 

if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['a2'], $_POST['a1'])) {
    $mail->Subject = 'Formularz kontaktowy - Cargo-trans.biz';
    //Keep it simple - don't use HTML
    //$mail->isHTML(false);
    //Build a simple message body
    $mail->Body = <<<EOT

<p style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>Imię i naziwsko:</b> {$_POST['a1']} </p>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>E-mail:</b> {$_POST['a2']} </p>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>Telefon kontaktowy:</b> {$_POST['a3']} </p>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>Temat:</b> {$_POST['a4']} </p>
<br>
<p style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>Wiadomość:</b> {$_POST['a5']} </p> 
<br>
<img src = "http://cargo-trans.biz/resources/img/napis.png" style="margin-top:10px;">
EOT;
    //Send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        //The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo
        //but you shouldn't display errors to users - process the error, log it on your server.
        $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
    } else {
        $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
    }
} else {
    $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would improve the script by adding an encoding check before sending - for example like this:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $subject_or_message_or_any_string);
```

also I wouldn't display the info if the mail failed to send instead of that I would rather use something like:

```
 if (!$mail->Send())
 {
   LogErrorMessage("Mailer Error: %s", $mail->ErrorInfo);
  die ("Sorry, mail could not be sent");
}
```

Next I would send or log IP address of user that sent the email form - for cases he likes to spam, you can block him easily.